# jQuery .effect() messing with webpage style

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am a beginner trying to work on small projects for practice. I have been working on a small game for my son and am having a small issue with the jQuery `.effect()` animation. When the correct div is clicked, it has the `.effect('bounce')` animation, but it is messing with the div's location on the page.
[Here is the link to the game.](http://www.googledrive.com/host/0BzZdWydvpDvmfm1PZDRMTVVMR3BvREpTaG8yZVgyRVFhek1ZcGd4cWNpSDFYYXNLeGp0QUU) How can I stop this from happening? I am assuming an edit in my CSS.
Sorry if I do not respond quickly, I am posting this before I go to sleep (tried solving this all evening), thanks in advance!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wrong').click(function() {
        $(this).effect('explode');
    });
    
    $('.right').click(function() {
        $(this).effect('bounce', {times:3}, 500);
        $('#level1').delay(700).slideUp('slow');
        $('#level2').delay(710).slideDown('slow');
    });
});
```

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    height: 100%;
}

#level1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
}

#level2 {
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.inner-container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.question {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin: 0;
}

.circles {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.red {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 5%;
}

.blue {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0 5%;
}

.green {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    margin: 0 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
        <title>Color Game</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="level1">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <p class="question">Which color is <span style="color: blue">BLUE</span></p>
                <div class="circles">
                    <div class="red wrong"></div>
                    <div class="blue right"></div>
                    <div class="green wrong"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="level2">
            <div class="inner-container">
                <p class="question">Which color is <span style="color: green">GREEN</span></p>
                <div class="circles">
                    <div class="blue wrong"></div>
                    <div class="red wrong"></div>
                    <div class="green right"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the bounce affect doesn't like Relative positioning and margins.

Try this CSS out:

```
   html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align:center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#level1 {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;  
    width: 100%;  
}

#level2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.inner-container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: thin black solid;
}

.question {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 5%;
    margin: 0;
}

.circles {
    text-align: center;
}

.red {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 30%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}

.blue {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 45%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}

.green {
    position: absolute;
    top: 300px;
    left: 60%;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

I ran it locally and it looks like it works.

Edit: You might want to turn the borders off. I just turned them on so that I could see the containers that the balls were in.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll try this out as soon as I get back to work. I'm still trying to learn the differences between the available positions on CSS.

Comment: Thank you again, that solved it. I better learn the positions a little quicker!